# Join two data frames based on one column of a frame and two columns of another

Tags: r

So I have two data frames, info and towers, with examples in the following:

Info:

```
ID             Date
1132           01/09/2015
1156           02/09/2015
1132           04/09/2015
1101           04/09/2015
```

Towers:

```
Tower   ID1   ID2
    1   1132  1101
    2   1520  1156
```

The values in the ID column of Info will always match either ID1 or ID2 in Towers. I want to join the frames based on that information, so my joined frame should be:

```
ID             Date         Tower
1132           01/09/2015       1
1156           02/09/2015       2
1132           04/09/2015       1
1101           04/09/2015       2
```

I know dplyr's semi_join makes something like what I need, but I understand it requires a match in both value and column name. Given that these columns have different names, I don't know if it will work properly. Is there a method I could use here?

Comment: `melt` Towers so your IDs are in the same column

Comment: You should probably look at `as.Date` and learn to format those properly. Also, please make your example reproducible next time so it can be copy-pasted in by others.

Comment: @Frank Yes I already worked in the format. For learning purposes, what do you mean exactly as a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm referring to the extra stuff in Sumedh's answer below, that looks like `structure(...)` If you copy-paste that into your R session, it will return your example data.frame. This sort of thing should be included with a question. For info on how to go about this, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't actually need to join; you can just make a new column, as long as you evaluate grouped by row:

```
Info %>% rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(Tower = Towers[ID == Towers$ID1 | ID == Towers$ID2, 'Tower'])
## Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
## Groups: <by row>
## 
## # A tibble: 4 x 3
##      ID       Date Tower
##   <int>     <fctr> <int>
## 1  1132 01/09/2015     1
## 2  1156 02/09/2015     2
## 3  1132 04/09/2015     1
## 4  1101 04/09/2015     1
```

or equivalently in full base R,

```
Info$Tower <- sapply(Info$ID, function(x){Towers[x == Towers$ID1 | x == Towers$ID2, 'Tower']})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::gather(df2, Tower2, ID, -Tower) %>% select(-Tower2) %>% right_join(df, "ID")
```

**df**

```
structure(list(ID = c(1132, 1156, 1132, 1101), Date = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("01/09/2015", "02/09/2015", "04/09/2015"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(Tower = 1:2, ID1 = c(1132L, 1520L), ID2 = c(1101L, 
1156L)), .Names = c("Tower", "ID1", "ID2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' format and `join` with the original dataset 'df' `on` 'ID'.

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df2), id.var="Tower", value.name = "ID")[df, on = "ID"][, variable := NULL][]
#  Tower   ID       Date
#1:     1 1132 01/09/2015
#2:     2 1156 02/09/2015
#3:     1 1132 04/09/2015
#4:     1 1101 04/09/2015
```

---

We could also do this without any join and using only `base R` (no external packages, without any loops (`sapply` is a loop in disguise)).  Here, the idea is to replicate the second dataset 'Tower' column by the number of columns except the 'Tower' i.e. `2`, set the `names` of that vector by `unlist`ing the columns of 'df2' except the 'Tower' (`unlist(df2[-1])`) and use that to match the 'ID' column in the first dataset (`as.character(df$ID)`) to return the 'Tower' that corresponds to the 'ID'.

```
df$Tower <- setNames( rep(df2$Tower, 2), unlist(df2[-1]))[as.character(df$ID)]
df$Tower
#[1] 1 2 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `melt`(also suggested by @SymbolixAU in comment) from `reshape2` package and using `df` & `df2` of @Sumedh's post.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
melt(df2,value.name = "ID",id.vars = "Tower") %>% right_join(df,by = "ID") %>% select(-variable)
```

We can also do this by using `base R` `reshape` function as this:

```
reshape(data = df2,direction = "long",varying = c("ID1","ID2"),v.names = "ID") %>% right_join(df,by = "ID") %>% select(-c(time,id))
```